# After updating Laravel to version 9, I can't sign an email inside a Mailable class

Tags: email, sign, laravel-9

After updating Laravel to version 9, I can't sign an email inside a Mailable class.

**my code in Laravel 6 worked:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NotificationEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $person;
    protected $data = [];

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($person, $data)
    {
        $this->person = $person;
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('mail.notification.senat')
            ->replyTo('noreply@example.com')
            ->subject('Test subject')
            ->with([
                'person' => $this->person,
                'data' => $this->data
            ])
            ->withSwiftMessage(function ($message){
                $smimeSigner = new \Swift_Signers_SMimeSigner(
                    config('mail.sign_cert'),
                    [config('mail.sign_key'), config('mail.sign_key_password')]
                );
                $message->attachSigner($smimeSigner);
            });
    }
}
```

**my code in Laravel 9 does not work:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Crypto\SMimeSigner;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Email;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class NotificationEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $person;
    protected $data = [];

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($person, $data)
    {
        $this->person = $person;
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build(): NotificationEmail {
        return $this->view('mail.notification.senat')
            ->replyTo('noreply@example.com')
            ->subject('Test subject')
            ->with([
                'person' => $this->person,
                'data' => $this->data
            ])
            ->withSymfonyMessage(function (Email $message){
                $certPath = storage_path(env('MAIL_SIGN_CERT'));
                $keyPath = storage_path(env('MAIL_SIGN_KEY'));
                // see: https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#signing-and-encrypting-messages
                $signer = new SMimeSigner($certPath, $keyPath, env('MAIL_SIGN_KEY_PASSWORD'));
                $signer->sign($message);
            })
            ;
    }
}
```

I know that Laravel 9 works with Symfony Mailer. However, the description does not use a Laravel Mailable environment.... See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#signing-and-encrypting-messages

The Laravel9 doc shows the way to customize: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail#customizing-the-symfony-message

But my solution does not work. I get an error, line 48 "$signer->sign($message);"
A message must have a text or an HTML part or attachments.

Do you have a clue and can you help?

Comment: Seems like a fairly clear error message to me. Your email does not have a body, a text, an actual message. You only set subject and reply-to. I mean, brevity is great, but it leaves you with nothing to sign.

Comment: If I remove the block ->withSymfonyMessage(function (Email $message), sending email works. A message is present in the Mailable context, but not in the Symfony\Component\Mime\Email context . However, I want to stay in the Mailable context.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an event listener for any outbound mail to achieve signing for all outbound mails with Laravel 9 / Symfony Mailer.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Listeners\Mail;

use Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Crypto\SMimeSigner;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Email;

class MessageSendingListener
{
    public function handle(MessageSending $event)
    {
        $signer = new SMimeSigner('/path/to/certificate.pem', 'path/to/private.key');
        $signedMessage = $signer->sign($event->message);

        $event->message->setHeaders($signedMessage->getHeaders());
        $event->message->setBody($signedMessage->getBody());
    }
}
```

Full explanation with the Event Service Provider:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-9-outbound-smime-messages

Symfony Docs S/MIME:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#s-mime-signer

Cheers :)